# Como receber os vários campos de uma view no controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

preciso criar um Insert de vários campos ao mesmo tempo! Meu sistema tem várias tabela e relacionamentos e estou com dificuldades nesse ponto. Tenho essa tela de cadastro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Com esse código:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
<div style="width: 100%; float: left;">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:200px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Alunos</th>
                    <th style="width:150px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Atribuir Nota</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>         
                    @{                   
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListaMatriculas.Count(); i++)
                    {
                    <tr>
                    <td>@Model.ListaMatriculas[i].Aluno.Nome</td>

                        <td style="text-align:center;">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Matricula.IdMatricula" value="@Model.ListaMatriculas[i].IdMatricula" />
                                <input type="text" name="Nota" value="0" style="width: 30px;" /> 
                                 @Html.DropDownList("UnidadeCurricular.IdUnidadeCurricular", ViewBag.unidadecurricular_idunidadecurricular as SelectList, "")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                    }

                </tbody>  
        </table>

        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <b>Obs: Notas devem possuir valores de 0 a 100.</b>        
        </div>
</div>     
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <button class="btn btn-sucsess " type="submit">Salvar</button>
</div>
}
```

No entanto quando eu clico no enviar meu controller não recebe os valores dos campos, alguém pode me dar um Help, como posso fazer algo assim? Um link de exemplo ou algo do tipo...

Comment: você deve adicionar novos campos de input dinamicamente? isso? Ou apenas os campos que estão no "ListarMatriculas" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caso você deseje manter o sistema com `html` puro ou `razor`, modifique o atributo `name` de seus `inputs` e receba-os em forma de lista em suas actions, conforme exemplo abaixo.

**Html**

```
<tbody>         
   @{                   
   for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListaMatriculas.Count(); i++)
   {
     <tr>
        <td>@Model.ListaMatriculas[i].Aluno.Nome</td>    
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <input type="hidden" name="Matriculas" value="@Model.ListaMatriculas[i].IdMatricula" />
            <input type="text" name="Notas" value="0" style="width: 30px;" /> 
            @Html.DropDownList("UnidadesCurriculares", ViewBag.unidadecurricular_idunidadecurricular as SelectList, "")
        </td>
     </tr>
  }
  }   
</tbody>
```

**Razor**

```
<tbody>         
   @{                   
   for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListaMatriculas.Count(); i++)
   {
     <tr>
        <td>@Model.ListaMatriculas[i].Aluno.Nome</td>    
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            @Html.Hidden("Matriculas",Model.ListaMatriculas[i].IdMatricula)
            @Html.TextBox("Notas")
            @Html.DropDownList("UnidadesCurriculares", ViewBag.unidadecurricular_idunidadecurricular as SelectList, "")
        </td>
     </tr>
  }
  }   
</tbody>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(IList<int> Matriculas, IList<string> Notas, IList<int> UnidadesCurriculares)
{
     return View();
}
```

Deste modo, você irá receber três listas de parâmetros de acordo com o que está em sua View. Note, contudo, que da forma como está implementado as três listas não estão relacionadas entre sí. Para isto, é necessário utilizar uma outra abordagem.

Comment: O `<input name>` precisa ser indexado também para funcionar. Aliás, este é o jeito meio brucutu de fazer funcionar. É quase perigoso, a meu ver.

Comment: Concordo @CiganoMorrisonMendez, estou editando a resposta para incluir os input's utilizando a sintaxe Razor, mas quis aproveitar o exemplo dele e fazer as mínimas alterações antes.

Comment: Vinícius, obrigado pela resposta! Apesar ser meio brucutu...rs... Como já faço os relacionamentos pelo campos ocultos, não deu problema! Consegui trazer as listas para o controller e fiz um for para enviar para uma DAO que tem o método insert no banco! Valeu mesmo... por hora resolveu! Mas vou tentar usar o BeginCollection com mais calma... em outro exemplo!

Answer (score 4):

Esse é mais um clássico caso de usar o pacote [BeginCollectionItem.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/)

Primeiro, instale o pacote via **NuGet** com o seguinte comando:

> Install-Package BeginCollectionItem

Após isso, mude sua view para isso:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
<div style="width: 100%; float: left;">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:200px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Alunos</th>
                    <th style="width:150px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Atribuir Nota</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>     
                  @foreach(var matricula in Model.ListaMatriculas)
                  {
                    Html.RenderPartial("_Matriculas",matricula);
                  }   
                </tbody>  
        </table>

        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <b>Obs: Notas devem possuir valores de 0 a 100.</b>        
        </div>
</div>     
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <button class="btn btn-sucsess " type="submit">Salvar</button>
</div>
}
```

Sua view agora está chamando uma partial que contém os dados que você precisa.

E sua partialView **_Matricula** ficará assim:

```
@model ModelMatriculaAqui

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ListaMatriculas"))
{
  <tr>
  <td>@Model.ListaMatriculas[i].Aluno.Nome</td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdMatricula)
              @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nota)
             @Html.DropDownList("UnidadeCurricular.IdUnidadeCurricular", ViewBag.unidadecurricular_idunidadecurricular as SelectList, "")//Sugiro alterar para um dropDownListFor(), caso sua viewModel possua essa propriedade
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

No resto, basta continuar a fazer da mesma forma.

> Qualquer dúvida, esse problema já possui [diversas respostas nesta pesquisa.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999%20%20begincollectionitem)

Comment: Randrade, vi outras respostas suas para esse caso e muitas falam do BeginCollectionItem, mas não consegui fazer funcionar! Vou tentar novamente com mais calma, por hora tive que apagar fogo... e usei na forma de IList<> passando no controller, como são poucos campos consegui de prima e resolveu o problema... mesmo sendo meio brucutu a solução! Valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: @CarlosCavalheiro Fica a seu critério. Se quiser ajuda, ficarei feliz em lhe explicar melhor.